# How to detect outlier in data using sliding IQR in Python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation, moving-average, anomaly-detection

Ok so I've been working on this project where I am trying to detect an anomaly and relate it to some certain phenomenon. I know that pandas have builtin functions i.e. pd.rolling(window= frequency).statistics_of_my_choice() but for some reasons I am not getting the desired results. I have calculated rolling mean, r.median, r.upper & lower = mean +- 1.6 r.std.

But when I plot it, the upper and lower bounds are always above the data. IDK what's happening here, it doesn't make sense. Please take a look at the figure for a better understanding.

Here's what I am getting:

[image: Here's what I am getting]

and here's what I want to achieve:

[image: This is what I want to acheive]

Here's the paper that I am trying to implement:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/374567172_Analysis_of_Ionospheric_Anomalies_before_the_Tonga_Volcanic_Eruption_on_15_January_2022/figures

Here's my code snippet

```
def gen_features(df):
    
    df["ma"] = df.TEC.rolling(window="h").mean()
    df["mstd"] = df.TEC.rolling(window="h").std()
    df["upper"] = df["ma"] + (1.6* df.mstd)
    df["lower"] = df["ma"] - (1.6* df.mstd)
    
    return df
```

Comment: If you can supply part of the data, that would be great. I will work on a random dataset for now...

Comment: Also seems that you have a lot of nans in your data - why are your plots discontinuous?

Comment: That's true there are nans in some stations basically I will completely remove those stations and interpolate the data using bfill or fill for those with fewer nans.

Answer (score 1):

From the publication:

"*Since the solar activity cycle is 27 days, this paper uses 27 days as the sliding window
to detect the ionospheric TEC perturbation condition before the volcanic eruption. The
upper bound of TEC anomaly is represented as
UB =Q2+
1.5
IQR
and the lower bound
as LB =Q2−1.5IQR*"

Implementing this in pandas:

```
# no seed for random, to try it many times
dataLength = 1000 # datalength
data = np.random.randint(1, 100, dataLength) # generate random data
outlierPercentage = 1 # controls amount of outliers in the data
outlierCount = int(dataLength/100 * outlierPercentage) # count of outliers
outlierIdx = np.random.choice(dataLength, outlierCount, replace=False) # choose randomly between the index of the outlier
data[outlierIdx] = np.random.randint(-300, 300, outlierCount) # choose a random int between -300 and 300
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': data}) # generate the datafrane
winSize = 5 # define size of window 
# the statistics calculations...
Mean = df["Data"].rolling(window=winSize).mean()
Q1 = df["Data"].rolling(window=winSize).quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df["Data"].rolling(window=winSize).quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
# assigning the upper limit and lower limit
df["UL"] = Mean + 1.5 * IQR
df["LL"] = Mean - 1.5 * IQR
# detect the outliers
outliersAboveUL = df[(df['Data'] > df['UL'])].index
outliersBelowLL = df[(df['Data'] < df['LL'])].index
```

Plotting gives you this:

[image: plot]

Imported packages:

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

As you can see, this is a very basic example. I mainly added the correct calculation of the IQR. If you want a more detailed answer, I would need a sample of your data...

**V2.0: with data from OP**

This is currently what I have with the same approach:

```
df = pd.read_csv("airaStation.csv", index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
winSize = "29D" # define size of window 
# the statistics calculations...
Mean = df["TEC"].rolling(window=winSize).mean()
Q1 = df["TEC"].rolling(window=winSize).quantile(0.25)
Q3 = df["TEC"].rolling(window=winSize).quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
# assigning the upper limit and lower limit
df["UL"] = Mean + 1.5 * IQR
df["LL"] = Mean - 1.5 * IQR
# detect the outliers
outliersAboveUL = df[(df['TEC'] > df['UL'])].index
outliersBelowLL = df[(df['TEC'] < df['LL'])].index
```

The plot:

[image: results]

Comment: Just re-read the definition of Q1, Q2 and Q3... "are the upper interquartile, median and lower interquartile, respectively". Well, they defined Q2 as a mean actually, with Q2 =(x1+x2)/2. Regardless.. if you want to calculate the bound by relying on the median, just change `.mean()` to `.median()`

Comment: Nope I tried with the "29D" window but the result is completely off.

Comment: Here's the data I am currently working with.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rwplIYNHOJudJ6jliO_3tJN7mOSx2JMK/view?usp=sharing

and here's what I got after using your technique

Comment: how does your df look like?

Comment: Am not sure if you have enough reputation to edit your code. But please show me how you imported the data.

Comment: I downloaded the data from the IGS station and then imported it using pd. read_csv() command.

Comment: csv are not type-set. Did you remember to convert the datetime column to datetime?

Comment: Yes, here's how I read it. 

df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

Comment: and did you set the date as an index?

Comment: i editted my answer to include currently what I have, @ImtiazNabi. The lower limit is below the data and the upper limit is above. What seems to be the problem in this case?

Comment: Thank you so much yeah İ saw it. But İ was thinking that the data may exceed the upper bound which İ can call an anomaly but in our case the bounds are also increasing with the data meaning that the data will always stay within bounds no matter how bigger the spike gets

Comment: Also, if you take a look at the second graph in the post (one that I want to achieve) the upper and lower bounds have a clear trend just like the data as compared to ours which is according to the author '29D' moving average.

Comment: I have read parts of the paper and I have to say, the quality is not worthy at all of being published. But that's MDPI... In any case, it seems to me that they chose a much smaller window. Something like 2 datapoints. Which they somehow also mention in their publication with the defintion of Q1 Q2 Q3

Comment: Yeah, I am also thinking the same. One more thing that I just found is that some authors are using the builtin MATLAB normfit function and calling the muCi and sigmaCi upper and lower bounds. I am so confused why are even such papers getting accepted in first place.

Comment: MDPI has to make money somehow :D